# Translations package: Where in texfm to put trsl files

Tags: packages

I am installing the translations package, as it is required by the newest acro package. Where would I put the trsl files that come with translations? I don't think it matters, but I'm using TeXLive from Cygwin.

I've posted this to:
http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=26680 and [Translations package: Where in texfm to put trsl files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/267027/translations-package-where-in-texfm-to-put-trsl-files)

Comment: The same place you put the `sty` file. But the package already is part of TeX Live. It shouldn't be necessary to install it manually...

Comment: Thanks, I posted my response in the LaTeX Community link because it's not an answer and too long for a comment.  I'd like to mark your comment as an answer....would you be able to post it as such?